# What does 'ride in on' mean and what does it have to do with horses?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Fuck me and the horse I rode in on.

To me, this sentence makes no sense. I stumbled across it as I watched the premiere episode of the Watchmen TV series. What does it mean? I know the idiom 'drive a coach and horses through' but it clearly has nothing to do with it. I couldn't find any other idiom with driving horses in. Why 'drive in on'? There's no such a phrasal verb, not that I could find. It's all such nonsense. You can find the transcript of the episode [here](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=watchmen-2019&episode=s01e01).

Comment: You can ***ride** [on]* or ***drive*** a coach (with or without horses), but you can only ***ride a horse***, not drive it,

Comment: I've never heard the expression, but the sense of 'rode in on' is 'the horse on which I rode in'.

Comment: You can be said to be 'driving' a horse when you make it pull a plough, cart, sledge, etc. Horses trained for such work are called 'driving horses'. "Equestrian Discipline: Driving
Driving can be an alternative career for a riding horse, but it can be dangerous for horses and humans." _The Horse_ magazine

Comment: "You can drive a horse to water, but you cannot necessarily make it drink, it appears. " - The _Daily Telegraph_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be related to the non-vulgar idiom "get off your high horse" which means to stop being stuck up or conceited about something.  I would bet this idiom is derived from western TV shows which were popular in the 50's and 60's, or possibly related to that type of American culture.

The implication is that you think you are better than anyone else.

Comment: Aah, I should've guessed, I knew that idiom. Thanks

Comment: I bet none of those western TV shows actually featured ***Fuck** you and the horse you rode in on!* But the earliest written example I can find for the specific sequence ***you and the horse you rode in on*** seems to be a 1967 text referring back to an earlier army discipline issue ([**in 1956**,](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7P2wAAAAIAAJ&q=%22you+and+the+horse+you+rode+in+on%22&dq=%22you+and+the+horse+you+rode+in+on%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKtbWMzbDmAhUxrXEKHVJJCukQ6AEIKTAA)) when an army lieutenant insulted a corporal using "words to that effect" (incl. ***fuck**!*).

Comment: This answer could use some supporting evidence.

Comment: Partridge dates *high horse* to "ca. 1715" and its use with "get off" to the19th century, so I hope you didn't bet much on your hunch.